# Forecast interval for ARIMA and ARIMA-GARCH model with $d\geq 1$

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, garch

I have a question connected with confidence interval calculation. 
So, let's have a ARIMA(p, 1, q)-GARCH(P, Q) model with drift: $\phi(L) \omega(t) = \theta_{0} + \theta(L) \varepsilon(t)$, where $\omega(t) = \Delta x(t)$.

In this case (and cases $d \geq 2$) I can get point forecast $\hat{x}_{l}(t)$ as $\hat{x}_{l}(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{l}\hat{\omega}_{k}(t) + \theta_{0}l + x(t)$. But how should I calculate interval forecast in this case? Could anyone give me an answer or get a link on the good manual?